# NSDate to NSTextField without string Formatting?

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to write the value of a NSDate into a NSTextField but I don't want to format the NSDate into NSString first. The user interface already has an NSDateFormatter object in place and place and it worked fine already when the field was bound to the NSDate.

But now we can't use binding anymore and need to set the Textfield value manually. But we still want to use the NSDateFormatter.

For me it seems like this can not be done. All the samples I found convert the NSDate into a string first before sending it to the TextField. Also if I do it like that I need to convert back the date after the user entered a new value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `-setObjectValue:` (declared on `NSControl`) to have the `NSDate` be routed through the attached formatter.

Similarly, the `-objectValue` method should convert the displayed string back into an `NSDate` and return that.